# mysql sql error when using the row_number

Tags: mysql, sql

This query is throwing error, it seems correct but i am getting an error

```
WITH Rows AS (SELECT *,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY userid asc) as [Row]
FROM users 
WHERE 1=1 
)
SELECT * FROM Rows
WHERE Row >= 1 and Row <= 10
```

error i am getting while running the above statement is:

```
 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Rows AS (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY userid asc)
  FROM users 
  ' at line 1
```

Comment: First of all, is your version 8+?

Comment: no, this is not version 8

Comment: btw`Rows` is a reserved keyword,use a different word,even if  your version is  8+

Comment: so you are using this will not work in previous versions, seems odd, then how can i run with old version

Comment: still does not work even after renaming

Comment: because window analytic function `row_number()` is not supported for  version prior to 8

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan MySQL under MySQL 8 does not know CTE (`WITH ... AS (..) ..`) and or window functions for that matter..

Answer (score 1):

Your error is on `Rows` because MySQL does not recognize the CTE.

Then, MySQL also does not recognize `[`, so you want to use a more reasonable name.  In MySQL 8+, that would be something like:

```
WITH Rows AS (
      SELECT *,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY userid asc) as seqnum
      FROM users 
)
SELECT *
FROM Rows
WHERE seqnum <= 10;
```

You don't need to compare to `1`.  That is definitional.

Of course, this, in turn, is overkill.  The CTE is unnecessary:

```
SELECT *,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY userid asc) as seqnum
FROM users 
ORDER BY userid
LIMIT 10;
```

But this will still fail, because MySQL versions started recognizing CTEs and window functions in the same version.

So, you can just use variables:

```
SELECT u.*, (@rn := @rn + 1) as seqnum
FROM users u CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT @rn := 0) params
ORDER BY userid
LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: but i am using pagination server side, will that not limit its usage

Comment: the last query which i am using in your answer

Comment: @CDN . . . The last query -- with `offset` -- is the typical approach to pagination in MySQL.